# Cause of a OutOfMemoryError with React native Android

Tags: android, react-native, out-of-memory

I'm developping an app with React native and my last version in release mode crashes after 20-30 seconds with the following generated logcat:

```
02-19 23:52:10.777 32717-32717/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my.app, PID: 32717
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: std::bad_alloc
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeArray.pushInt(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.Timing$TimerFrameCallback.doFrame(Timing.java:89)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:134)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:105)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:909)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

The app never crashes in dev mode.

How can I know what causes this? Is there a leak somewhere? What steps are to be followed to know more about it?

Comment: also try to add
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
answer from here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks)

Answer (score 12):

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
   android:largeHeap="true"
```

Adding largeHeap seems fix it

Please refer this [git issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6799)

Comment: In my case it is not working. Any new ideas how to solve this error?

Comment: @jocoders were you able to fix this issue? I am also getting this in my app

Comment: @Sangeeta no, i could not find the real cause of this issue